# SharePoint 2007 Mixed Mode Authentication with a MSSQL twist?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sharepoint-2007, forms-authentication, windows-authentication, basic-authentication

I'm maintaining and extending a SharePoint 2007 *internet* website which has a extensive custom ASP.NET 2.0 application integrated with custom MSSQL 2008 database.

The application uses Windows Authentication hooked to Active Directory and all accounts are domain accounts on Active Directory Domain Controller.

Users log in from their remote locations via internet browser using Basic Authentication over SSL.

The MSSQL 2008 uses SUSER_SNAME extensively throughout the stored procedures to identify which user is making the procedure request and modify the query used accordingly.

I have been asked to switch from Basic Authentication to Forms Based Authentication.

I have the following questions:

1) What are the dangers in making the switch from Basic Authentication to Forms Based Authentication in SharePoint 2007?

2) Do I have additional problems waiting for me due to the use of SUSER_SNAME in the stored procedure?

3) Is a change like this relatively quick or would it potentially take me a lengthy time to debug failures in the system?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "**Active Directory membership provider**" to implement this change.
See this link [Active Directory membership provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262069%28v=office.12%29.aspx#section2)

1) There is no serious difference in security point of view between Basic Authentication and Form Based authentication.

2)  Using "Active Directory membership provider" does not affect using SUSER_SNAME.

3) It is very simple procedure.